# How to set featured image programmatically from url?

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I have some post id's and I want to set these posts' featured images from same url.

Here is my adding post codes:

```
$catid = get_cat_ID("XX Cat");

$my_post = array(); 
$my_post['post_title'] = $title; 
$my_post['post_content'] = $description; 
$my_post['post_status'] = 'publish'; 
$my_post['post_author'] = 1; 
$my_post['post_category'] = array( $catid ); 

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Example: post_id = 1 I want to set featured image to: example.com/image.png

How can I do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can set an image as post featured thumbnail when it is in your media library. To add an image in your media library you need to upload it to your server.

try this code:

```
// Add Featured Image to Post
$image_url        = 'http://s.wordpress.org/style/images/wp-header-logo.png'; // Define the image URL here
$image_name       = 'wp-header-logo.png';
$upload_dir       = wp_upload_dir(); // Set upload folder
$image_data       = file_get_contents($image_url); // Get image data
$unique_file_name = wp_unique_filename( $upload_dir['path'], $image_name ); // Generate unique name
$filename         = basename( $unique_file_name ); // Create image file name

// Check folder permission and define file location
if( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
  $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
} else {
  $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
}

// Create the image  file on the server
file_put_contents( $file, $image_data );

// Check image file type
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );

// Set attachment data
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
    'post_content'   => '',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
);

// Create the attachment
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );

// Include image.php
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

// Define attachment metadata
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );

// Assign metadata to attachment
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

// And finally assign featured image to post
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
```

ref url : http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-featured-image-url/

Modified as your requirement:
or that purpose ignore WordPress standard and upload your all post single image on your custom folder and add this image path or direct external image url into post as extra attribute meta field and when you will show post on your theme then just use your img with help of post id.
demo code:
for setting image

```
<?php
    update_post_meta ( 7, 'imgkey', 'www.url.path' );//7 is post id
?>
```

for getting image on your theme page where you want to show it

```
<?php
    $img_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'imgkey', true );
?>
<img src="<?php echo $img_value?>">
```

Note if you are new in WordPress post custom meta fields then read this article:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

or
unofficial article about custom fields: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-custom-fields-manually

Comment: I want to use only one image. But this code is adding one image more than one... Also I don't want to add different sizes of image. I want to upload image that has to be only original size...

Comment: i am updating my answer

Comment: How can I get url and name of image uploaded in an html form for this same code?

Comment: see above code $img_value will actually get the url of image

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: Works as intended. One of the best answers I have ever found. On Point and Nice comment notes. You would not need anything else.

Comment: Thanks @HassanSaeed, you just saved me at least a precious hour on my 1st WP plugin.

Comment: for picsum api images

do this in above code
$tmp_file = download_url( 'https://picsum.photos/1200/675' );
$image_data  = file_get_contents( $tmp_file ); // Get image data

Answer (score 32):

if you have to load an image and then assign as thumbnail of the post, the quicker way is to use media_sideload_image and then set_post_thumbnail

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_sideload_image/

```
$url     = "http://url-of-the-image.jpg";
$post_id = [post id]
$desc    = "image description";

$image = media_sideload_image( $url, $post_id, $desc,'id' );

set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $image );
```

Comment: Now this is the real answer.

Comment: Nice answer, but only thing to watch out here is that you need to have file extension in url. If you have some API url which does not have file extension this will not work.

Comment: @Antonio You can use download_url( $image_url ) function

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/download_url/

Answer (score 4):

Just to complement @Naraj answer, if you are working in an external file, remember to add:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
```

if you do not add that you will get an error message saying that media_sideload_image is undefined.